# What's the difference between the 'Jewish-books' tag and the 'sefarim-books' tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I'm pretty new to this site, so please forgive me if I dont understand how this works. I recently asked [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14079/why-the-custom-to-switch-around-negative-sounding-numbers-such-as), and while searching for tabs to add i saw one titled 'sefarim-books' and one titled 'jewish-books'.

Is there a difference between the two?

Also, to tags really matter so much? I see a lot of discussion about them.

Comment: To format a tag in the text, put the tag name after " tag: " and the whole thing in brackets

Comment: (Specifically, square [brackets](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bracket), `[` and `]`.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes someone will start a tag for a category that already has a tag. Stackexchange has a feature called tag synonyms that allow tags to be mapped onto other tags so that all variations on a single theme can be combined into one tag.

It seems someone accidentally started [sefarim-books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefarim-books) when we already had [jewish-books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-books). Since the latter came first, I suggested a tag synonym to map the former to the latter. Once it gets 4 votes by members who have at least a answer score of 5 in this tag, it will come into effect. You can vote on it [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/jewish-books/synonyms). (Incidentally, if it gets 2 downvotes it will be deleted, but I don't expect that to happen in this case.)

In general, tags are a useful way of sorting all the varied information on our site and proper tagging can help users searching for content and avoid duplicate questions. Especially as the site continues to grow, proper organization will become more important. Now there is some debate about different tags because we are still determining how to group things, but in the long run it should settle down.

Comment: Do mods have the 5 point score restriction to suggest and vote? Also, are their votes binding?

Comment: I don't know whether we (mods) have the five-point restriction, and our votes aren't binding, but we have another means of making synonyms which is binding. (That is, unlike most things on the site, where everything a mod does is binding, for making a tag synonym a mod can *either* vote *or* Just Do It.)

Comment: @msh210 in that case, if I see a tag that needs to be synonymized but don't have the requisite score, is it appropriate for me to flag the answer and request it, or should I just wait patiently and answer some more questions?

Comment: You mean a tag that's on many posts? Bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning), or post a merger request here on meta. If the tag's on one post, then I guess it depends: If you really think the tag used should be a synonym, then bring it up in chat (with or without also editing the post to use the more common tag). If not, then just retag the post. MHO.

Comment: @msh210 for instance [this tag](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avodah-zarah) clearly should be synonymized into [this tag](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idolatry)

Comment: or [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/9-days) into [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nine-days)

Comment: Done, and done. Thanks.

Comment: @msh210 but you think in general I should point this out in chat not by flag for mods.

Comment: Flagging is for a specific post rather than a tag. But if it's a pain in the neck to go to chat for this, then sure, flag it. Again: MHO.